# How to integrate Gimbal SDK with Cordova-based app?

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, gimbal

I am creating a mobile app using gimbal beacon, apache cordova and ionic framework.

Based on quickstart tutorial from [Gimbal Doc](http://gimbal.com/doc/), i've created sample "Hello Gimbal Android" app with their android SDK which can be downloaded from [gimbal manager](https://manager.gimbal.com/).

This simple app can detect gimbal beacon while we **visit** or **leave** place/beacon.

Now, i'm continue to integrate this sample "Hello Gimbal Android" app *(which is build in java with gimbal SDK)* with my cordova-based app *(which i develop with HTML, CSS and Javascript)*.

I found [cordova gimbal plugin](https://github.com/happydenn/cordova-plugin-gimbal) but unfortunately it only support on iOS. Should i create my own cordova plugin for android?

Anyone has experience before?

Answer (score 0):

This link supports Gimbal 2 within Phonegap/Cordova... and supports Android and iOS. Gimbal 2 is BLE, so the Android and iOS OS must be at a level where BLE is implemented.

I'm in the process of trying to make this work in Phonegap. I will update when I do.

https://github.com/happydenn/cordova-plugin-gimbal2

Comment: I was able to make this work on Phonegap w/ no issues. Good plugin.